# What is a recursive starter function?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am learning about recursion (using C++) and my professor is referring to this term that I'm not familiar with. I understand that a normal recursive function calls itself (very useful for solving a maze), but a recursive starter function doesn't make sense to me because wouldn't that just call itself and be a normal recursive function? Otherwise how can it be defined as recursive?

Comment: If you're not sure what your professor was talking about, the best person to ask for clarification would be your professor. There is no such common term as "recursive starter function" in C++.

Comment: My guess: The recursive call might have some extra arguments. So you might wish to hide these from the caller by wrapping the initial recursive call in a function with a simpler more relevant set of parameters. So the 'starter' function wouldn't be recursive, but it would kick off the recursion. However you should clarify this with your professor, he isn't doing you much of a favour by bandying about these relatively unknown terms without explaining what they mean.

Comment: In all fairness, a term becomes common by its repeated use. The pattern we're assuming (wrapper which sets up the extra parameters) is common, so it deserves a name. I'd personally think "recursion starter" is clearer, because the starter itself isn't recursive

Answer (score 3):

I think that the term denotes a function that prepares a call of indeed recursive function.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>

void reverse( char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( not ( n < 2 ) )
    {
        std::swap( s[0], s[n-1] );
        reverse( s + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    reverse( s, std::strlen( s ) );

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << reverse( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
olleH
```

Here the function

```
char * reverse( char *s );
```

is a recursive starter function.

The program above can be rewritten using a lambda expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    std::function<void( char *, size_t )> reverse 
    ( 
        [&]( char *s, size_t n )
        {
            if ( not ( n < 2 ) ) 
            {
                std::swap( s[0], s[n-1] );
                reverse( s + 1, n - 2 );
            }
        } 
    );

    reverse( s, std::strlen( s ) );

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << reverse( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```